# Investigate which certificate uses the driver

Tags: kernel, certificate, driver

I have an application which does ram analysis and it has a kernel driver or drivers. Is there any way to know (for example, from tool like procmon or registry analysis), which security certificates were used by app authors to sign in the kernel drivers?

Comment: Operating system? Which application?

Comment: Win 10, Magnet Ram Capturer